# How to skip null dummy nodes when traversing doubly linked lists

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, nosuchelementexception

I have a doubly linked list which looks like:

`null
1
2
3
null`

When I traverse the list using an iterator with the code below, the output prints exactly what is written above.

```
            Iterator<Integer> it = lst.iterator(); // tests iterator method
            while (it.hasNext()) {
              Integer val = it.next();

              System.out.println(val);
            }
```

However, I want to skip the null nodes as I traverse the list so that it only prints:

`1
2
3`

I cannot get my code to do that.  Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
            Iterator<Integer> it = lst.iterator(); // tests iterator method
            while (it.hasNext()) {
              Integer val = it.next();
              if (val == null)
                 it.next()

              System.out.println(val);
            }
```

The problem with that is that I get a NoSuchElementException error, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.  My guess is I get that error because when I get to the second null dummy node, I try to skip it, but there are no other nodes to jump to.

My question is, how can I change my code so that it prints each element in the doubly linked list while skipping both of the null dummy nodes?

Comment: A test of the value to avoid printing it is indicated, not to "skip" it.

Comment: Try using `if(val!=null)System.out.println(val);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to use the test in combination with the println:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Integer val = it.next();
   if (val != null){
       System.out.println(val);
   }
}
```

If you do an extra next in the loop, you skip one hasNext, and that's why you run into the exception.

Comment: This fixed it!  Thank you!  Thank you also for explaining the reason for the error.  That definitely helps clear it up.